Integrating Keyboard Input for Timeline Functionality in a HoloLens Unity Project on WUP
I created a Unity project for Windows Universal Platform (WUP), working with HoloLens, and used VuMark for marker recognition. After scanning the VuMark, a canvas appears. I have to also add that I use MRTK3, Visual Studio 2022 and unity version 2022.3.25f1.
I want to configure it so that pressing F1 makes an object appear inside the canvas dialog box, and pressing F2 saves the current game object and adds a new one. This should function as a timeline. Is it possible to use the keyboard for input in a WUP project? If so, could you provide guidance on how to implement this?
void Update() { 
    // Check if F1 or F2 keys are pressed 
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F1)) { 
        ActivateNextObject(); 
    } else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F2)) { 
        ActivateNextObject(); 
    } 
}

I’m facing an issue where there is no connection between my PC and the HoloLens to receive input from the keyboard when I run the project on the HoloLens. How can I connect these two devices together?

I wrote a code to  void Update()
{
// Check if F1 or F2 keys are pressed
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F1))
{
ActivateNextObject();
}
else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F2))
{
ActivateNextObject();
}
} I’m facing an issue where there is no connection between my PC and the HoloLens to receive input from the keyboard when I run the project on the HoloLens. How can I connect these two devices together?

Welcome on board, please edit your post instead of adding code via comment. I will integrate your comment into your post right now.

HoloLens dose not natively support keyboard inputs and it is designed for gestures, voice, and motion controllers. I recommend using an alternative that leverages HoloLens strengths. For more details about Input System of HoloLens, please start from Controllers - MRTK 2 | Microsoft Learn.
